# Refactoring a destructuring into an object destructuring

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring my code, which involves converting a big list of `let` statements into an object called `personDetails`:

```js
personDetails = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    zipcode: 'xyz',
    age: 20,
    gender: 'm'
}
```

Currently, I am destructuring the values returned from my array like this:

```js
[firstName, lastName] = getNames(zipcode, age, gender)
```

This works fine. But now that I am switching to an object, how do I update that object with the returned values? I will be passing in the object as an argument like this:

```js
getNames(personDetails)
```

Do I have to do something like this?

```js
personDetails = getNames(personDetails)
```

The called function might look something like this (abbreviated):

```js
const getNames(personDetails) => {
  personDetails.firstname = 'Jack'
  personDetails.lastName = 'Jones'
}
```

Comment: Could you please once again explain what you are trying to do? Kinda hard to figure out

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that demonstrates the issue? I have trouble linking the pieces of code together and identify what belongs where.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the object inside the function, and then return the modified object?

Comment: Also please provide a function that is syntactically correct. Object destructuring is based on the name of the property, and properties names can't have dots in them. (Well, they can, but not the way it is displayed here.)

Comment: Are you asking how to destructure an object instead of an array?

Comment: Can you please show us your **entire** current code (i.e. how `getNames` is defined, where `zipcode`, `age`, and `gender` come from, and how you use `firstName` and `lastName`), as well as how you tried to change it?

Comment: I may be using the wrong terminology since I am about 8 months into my self-taught programming of JavaScript. I have accepted a solution now which answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Your arrow function had a typo, you must declare it with an `=` before the argument, like this:

```
const getNames = (personDetails) => {      // Correct
const getNames(personDetails) => {         // Incorrect
```

**2)** Inside your function, you weren't modifying an object key, but creating a new one instead. Remember that objects keys differs if you use upper or lowercase letters, `firstName` and `firstname` are not the same key.

**3)** Last, when you create an argument in your function, do not declare it with the same name of the global object, since it could create unexpected results. Then, you don´t need to destructure your object, just **return the complete object**.

```js
let personDetails = {    // Using let
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  zipcode: 'xyz',
  age: 20,
  gender: 'm'
};

const getNames = (obj) => {    // obj is the argument
  obj.firstName = 'Jack';
  obj.lastName = 'Jones';

  return obj;    // Return complete object
}

personDetails = getNames(personDetails);

console.log(personDetails);
```

If you want to destructure the object, you can do it too the same way you do it with the array, but I wouldn´t recommend it because it makes the code less clear:

```js
const personDetails = {    // Using const
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  zipcode: 'xyz',
  age: 20,
  gender: 'm'
};

const getNames = (obj) => {    // obj is the argument
  obj.firstName = 'Jack';
  obj.lastName = 'Jones';

  return [obj.firstName, obj.lastName];    // Return part of object as an array
}

[personDetails.firstName, personDetails.lastName] = getNames(personDetails);

console.log(personDetails);
```

Comment: What you wrote there made perfect sense to me. I get a message saying that personDetails is a constant. When I declared the object, I used const because I read you should normally declare an object with const. But this object gets frequently updated. Should I just use let instead for the fix?

Comment: If you are using const in the object you wouldn´t be able to reassign a value to the complete object (first example i did), but able to destructure the object and change each key. So if you want to use first solution just use let or var.